# Having trouble replacing the values to correct this mplDeprecation

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid.anchored_artists import AnchoredText
```

> .local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/deprecation.py:107: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: The mpl_toolkits.axes_grid module was deprecatedin version 2.1. Use mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 and mpl_toolkits.axisartist provies the same functionality instead.
>     warnings.warn(message, mplDeprecation, stacklevel=1)
>   python /home/mmt/RealEstate/predict.py

Comment: what you've tried? Just asking?

Answer (score 1):

There is no real question being asked here; but supposedly you want to

```
from matplotlib.offsetbox import AnchoredText
```